# Xamarin.Forms Previewer - An android application project must reference a project containing this xaml file in order to render in the previewer

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting the following error when trying to preview XAML documents via the Xamarin.Forms Previewer while in Visual Studio.

> An Android Application project must reference the project containing
>   this xaml file in order to render in the previewer.

I've tried

1. Closing the XAML file and reopening
2. Verified the Java SDK path locations are correct
3. Clean and Rebuilding Solution

Im using Xamarin 4.5.0.486, Android SDK 7.3.1.2, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 10.10, Visual Studio Community Version 2017

[image]

Comment: Are you using forms?

Comment: Yes. Im using the latest version.

Comment: It seems like the projects are not linked... Did you tried exclude the `bin` and `obj` folders, clean up the solution and rebuilt it all? I've some troubles using more then one instance of VS too.

Comment: Yes. I tried both, but it is still showing this message.

Comment: VS on mac or windows?

Comment: Im using VS on Windows 10(latest update) with  (VS Community 2017)

Comment: Does your android project have a reference to your forms PCL?

Comment: Yes. It is having reference to the PCL. Also I'm using a separate c# project to keep my business logic. I have added a reference to that project too.

Comment: Anybody figure this out? Having this issue with VS 15.6.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your android project and make sure the dll of your PCL/.net standard project is reference. In my own case, its referenced but shows a yellow color. I deleted the reference and re-reference by right clicking on the android project>projects>solution>select the PCL/.net standard project > ok

[image]

Comment: Just to add to this I had to close and re-open the xaml file after adding the project references to get the preview to work.

Comment: It works, I also had to recompile project and then it rendered ok

Answer (score 0):

just check if your project structure fits the file system/ folder structure.

rename the folders to fit the project structure helped in my case.

like if your Android Shared Project name is : "AppBla.Shared" and your folder name is 
"App4" or something.

Answer (score 0):

i think my solution is help this problem.

it has two problem, one is the solution path, the other one is dll reference.

I'll explain it with the example program Todo(example forum).

first, you have to clean your solution path like below png

[image: png]

secondly, you have to clean your all project (Todo, Todo.android, Todo.ios...)

then, you'll be able to see warning at Todo.dll(in Todo.android referense)

then, you have to delete Todo.dll

and build your Todo project then will create new dll

finally, Add it('new dll') to Todo.anroid project reference and include a Todo project in your Todo.android project(Todo.android reference add-> project -> check Todo).

[image: check Todo]

and restart visual studio

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions here worked for me. Upgrading to VS 2019 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

1. Right Click on the project
2. Click on Manage NuGet Packages
3. Click on the Update Tab
4. Select Xamarin.Forms and hit update

[Update Xamarin.Forms NuGet Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tifs7.png)

Comment: This answer is analogous to telling someone to hit Alt-F4.  This is a great way to go from having a working project to spending three days getting your solution to build again. NuGet update and pray.

Answer (score -1):

This problem can occur for a number of issues. Main problem is that for some reason Android's project can't build or be run inside Xamarin.

For me, the issue was that the latest JDK was not installed. My JRE was, but not JDK. Once I reinstalled JDK and restarted Visual Studio. All was well.