# Previewer will not load

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was building a mobile app in VS 2017 and upgraded to VS 2019. When I first opened the solution the Android and iOS projects appeared to be unloaded. I forgot to install the mobile tools so I did, then reopened the the solution. Now those appear reloaded, but the Previewer will not render. The error is:

> your application project must reference the xamarin.forms nuget in order to use the previewer.

I have updated the Nuget for the solution. One site told me to add this to the contentPage:

> xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Previewer;assembly=Previewer"

And it cannot find the assembly Previewer.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please check if you have installed xamarin.forms nuget for both the iOS/Android project and the shared project? You can have a try with the solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000393/xamarin-forms-previewer-an-android-application-project-must-reference-a-projec).

Comment: Thanks for that. I did see this one. Neither of mine are checked, but when I check those it says it cannot cause it would be a circular reference.

Comment: You should only check the shared project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing with the similar problem several times. It wasn't about 'Previewer', but

> your application project must reference the xamarin.forms nuget

I did the following steps to solve the problem:

1. Select solution -> RMB -> Clean Solution.
2. Select solution -> RMB -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...
3. Uninstall Xamarin.Forms for ALL projects: go to Install tab, find Xamarin.Forms, select ALL projects, click Uninstall.
4. (optional; Android only) Sometimes (if your project is very old) it also might be helpful to uninstall all Xamarin.Android.Support.* packages.
5. (optional) Restart VS 2019.
6. Select solution -> RMB -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...
7. Install Xamarin.Forms for ALL projects. If you did step 4 then don't forget to install required Xamarin.Android.Support.* packages for Android project.
8. Select solution -> RMB -> Build Solution. Or, in your case, go to 'Previewer'.